# URL rewrite checks for static files then rewrites to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

OK, I'm pants at rewrite rules in .htaccess files!

My desired scenario is (using the URL `http://doma.in/` as an example):

- First check to see if an `index.html` file exists in the `/public` sub-dir; if it does, serve it

  - If it did not; serve (rewrite to) `index.php`

To expand on my example, say we requested the URL `http://doma.in/js/foobar.js`:

- First check to see if an `foobar.js` file exists in the `/public/js` sub-dir; if it does, serve it

  - If it did not; serve (rewrite to) `index.php?controller=js%2Ffoobar.js`

That would cover static files but I also need URLs like `http://doma.in/foo`:

- First check to see if an `foo` file exists in the `/public` sub-dir; if it does, serve it

  - If it did not; serve (rewrite to) `index.php?controller=foo`

And a URL `http://doma.in/foo/bar`:

- We can assume the file `foo/bar` does not exists in the `/public` sub-dir as files can't be named like that.

  - So serve (rewrite to) `index.php?controller=foo&action=bar`

I'm sure if this complicated (for me) bit is covered then I can work query-strings into the occasion too; so `http://doma.in/foo/bar/foo/bar` would serve `index.php?controller=foo&action=bar&querystring=foo%2Fbar`.

I'd also like to make sure that a trailing slash is handled the same as if a trailing slash was omitted, for example: `http://doma.in/foo/bar/foo/bar` and `http://doma.in/foo/bar/foo/bar/`

I'll handle 404s from within my app as if the file did not exist, it would redirect to `index.php` which does exist - I'm happy with this unless you've a better solution :)

I really hope all this makes sense as I've been looking to find a solution to this scenario all day now and this is all I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#RewriteBase /prompt-v3/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/prompt-v3/(.*)$

RewriteCond $1 !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [R]
```

The commented-out lines deal with a sub-dir when on a remote host. So far I can redirect to the `/public` sub-dir if the file exists there and that's about it.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
#RewriteBase /sub-dir/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub-dir/(.*)$

RewriteRule ^index.html$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^public
RewriteCond $1 !^lib
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 ^public/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ lib/bootstrap.php [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^public/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 ^public/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ lib/bootstrap.php?path=%1 [L]
```

This will look for an index.html file in the public directory and if it does not exist rewrite the URL to lib/bootstrap.php. it in fact checks for any request as a static file in the public directory first and deals with canonicalisation too.

Answer (score 0):

Put this .htaccess in your document root

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # For /js/foobar.js (/js/*)
  RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /public/js/$1 [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1  [NC,L]

  # For foo/bar (/*/*?*)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /public/$1/$2 [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^public/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&querystring=%{QUERY_STRING}  [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```